# SwiftUI Multiple API Requests

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm fairly new to SwiftUI and I am trying to send in method1 request to an endpoint, get information and then pass it to method2 call. The problem is 2nd method is executing before I
receive from async information. How Can I prevent that from happening?

```
@Published var programme = [Programme]()
@Published var movies = [MovieDetails]()

init() {
    method1()
    method2()
}

func method1() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://someendpoint.com/") else {
        print("URL NOT FOUND")
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
        let channel = try!JSONDecoder().decode(Channel.self, from: data!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.programme = channel.schedule.programme
        }
    }
    .resume()
}

func method2() {
        let testmovie = self.programme[0].title_original <-- Receiving index out of range since haven't received information from method1
        let testyear = self.programme[0].year
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.someotherendpointt=\(testmovie)&y=\(testyear)") else {
            print("MOVIE URL NOT FOUND")
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            let movieDetails = try!JSONDecoder().decode([MovieDetails].self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.movies = movieDetails
            }
            
        }
        .resume()
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing both methods in the `init`. As they are **asynchronous**, the second method will start before the first one finishes.

You need to move the call to `method2` to the *end* of the `method1`:

```
init() {
    method1()
    // method2() // don't call immediately
}

func method1() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://someendpoint.com/") else {
        print("URL NOT FOUND")
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
        let channel = try!JSONDecoder().decode(Channel.self, from: data!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.programme = channel.schedule.programme
            self.method2() // call here - now you are sure that `self.programme` is set
        }
    }
    .resume()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked, it was so obvious and I couldn't figure out...